# Undefined references with WebRTC

Tags: c++, cmake, webrtc

I'm trying to build peer connection client from WebRTC examples with cmake to use it in my project.

I've included all webrtc libraries and so on to build it, but Im getting always the same issue:

```
CMakeFiles/webrtcbridge_node.dir/src/webrtcbridge_node.cc.o:(.rodata._ZTI18CustomSocketServer[_ZTI18CustomSocketServer]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for rtc::PhysicalSocketServer'
CMakeFiles/webrtcbridge_node.dir/src/conductor.cc.o: In function `Conductor::OnMessageFromPeer(int, std::string const&)':
conductor.cc:(.text+0x294d): undefined reference to `rtc::GetStringFromJsonObject(Json::Value const&, std::string const&, std::string*)'
conductor.cc:(.text+0x2aed): undefined reference to `rtc::GetStringFromJsonObject(Json::Value const&, std::string const&, std::string*)'
conductor.cc:(.text+0x2c01): undefined reference to `webrtc::CreateSessionDescription(std::string const&, std::string const&, webrtc::SdpParseError*)'
conductor.cc:(.text+0x2f46): undefined reference to `rtc::GetStringFromJsonObject(Json::Value const&, std::string const&, std::string*)'
conductor.cc:(.text+0x2fa7): undefined reference to `rtc::GetIntFromJsonObject(Json::Value const&, std::string const&, int*)'
conductor.cc:(.text+0x3004): undefined reference to `rtc::GetStringFromJsonObject(Json::Value const&, std::string const&, std::string*)'
conductor.cc:(.text+0x3190): undefined reference to `webrtc::CreateIceCandidate(std::string const&, int, std::string const&, webrtc::SdpParseError*)'
CMakeFiles/webrtcbridge_node.dir/src/conductor.cc.o: In function  `Conductor::OnSuccess(webrtc::SessionDescriptionInterface*)':
conductor.cc:(.text+0x53e9): undefined reference to `webrtc::CreateSessionDescription(std::string const&, std::string const&, webrtc::SdpParseError*)'
CMakeFiles/webrtcbridge_node.dir/src/conductor.cc.o: In function  `rtc::ArrayView<int, -4711l>::ArrayView<int>(int*, unsigned long)':
conductor.cc:(.text._ZN3rtc9ArrayViewIiLln4711EEC2IiEEPT_m[_ZN3rtc9ArrayViewIiLln4711EEC5IiEEPT_m]+0xd4): undefined reference to `rtc::FatalMessage::FatalMessage(char const*, int, std::string*)'
conductor.cc:(.text._ZN3rtc9ArrayViewIiLln4711EEC2IiEEPT_m[_ZN3rtc9ArrayViewIiLln4711EEC5IiEEPT_m]+0x15a): undefined reference to  `rtc::FatalMessage::FatalMessage(char const*, int, std::string*)'
conductor.cc:(.text._ZN3rtc9ArrayViewIiLln4711EEC2IiEEPT_m[_ZN3rtc9ArrayViewIiLln4711EEC5IiEEPT_m]+0x200): undefined reference to `rtc::FatalMessage::FatalMessage(char const*, int, std::string*)'
CMakeFiles/webrtcbridge_node.dir/src/conductor.cc.o: In function  `rtc::ArrayView<rtc::IntervalRange, -4711l>::ArrayView<rtc::IntervalRange>(rtc::IntervalRange*, unsigned long)':
conductor.cc:(.text._ZN3rtc9ArrayViewINS_13IntervalRangeELln4711EEC2IS1_EEPT_m[_ZN3rtc9ArrayViewINS_13IntervalRangeELln4711EEC5IS1_EEPT_m]+0xd4): undefined reference to `rtc::FatalMessage::FatalMessage(char const*, int, std::string*)'
conductor.cc:(.text._ZN3rtc9ArrayViewINS_13IntervalRangeELln4711EEC2IS1_EEPT_m[_ZN3rtc9ArrayViewINS_13IntervalRangeELln4711EEC5IS1_EEPT_m]+0x15a): undefined reference to `rtc::FatalMessage::FatalMessage(char const*, int, std::string*)'
CMakeFiles/webrtcbridge_node.dir/src/conductor.cc.o:conductor.cc:(.text._ZN3rtc9ArrayViewINS_13IntervalRangeELln4711EEC2IS1_EEPT_m[_ZN3rtc9ArrayViewINS_13IntervalRangeELln4711EEC5IS1_EEPT_m]+0x200): more undefined references `rtc::FatalMessage::FatalMessage(char const*, int, std::string*)'
CMakeFiles/webrtcbridge_node.dir/src/conductor.cc.o: In function  `std::string* rtc::CheckEqImpl<unsigned long, unsigned long>(unsigned long const&, unsigned long const&, char const*)':
conductor.cc:(.text._ZN3rtc11CheckEqImplImmEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN3rtc11CheckEqImplImmEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x4b): undefined reference to `std::string* rtc::MakeCheckOpString<unsigned long, unsigned long>(unsigned long const&, unsigned long const&, char const*)'
CMakeFiles/webrtcbridge_node.dir/src/peer_connection_client.cc.o: In function `PeerConnectionClient::Connect(std::string const&, int, std::string const&)':
peer_connection_client.cc:(.text+0xc97): undefined reference to `rtc::SocketAddress::SetIP(std::string const&)'
CMakeFiles/webrtcbridge_node.dir/src/peer_connection_client.cc.o:(.rodata._ZTI20PeerConnectionClient[_ZTI20PeerConnectionClient]+0x28): undefined reference to `typeinfo for rtc::MessageHandler'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
webrtcbridge/CMakeFiles/webrtcbridge_node.dir/build.make:205: recipe for target 'webrtcbridge/webrtcbridge_node' failed
make[2]: *** [webrtcbridge/webrtcbridge_node] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:878: recipe for target 'webrtcbridge/CMakeFiles/webrtcbridge_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [webrtcbridge/CMakeFiles/webrtcbridge_node.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed 
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(webrtcbridge)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

#Include PkgConfig to detect GTK+ headers/library files
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED) 
pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)
pkg_check_modules(JSONCPP REQUIRED jsoncpp)

include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(LIBYUV_LIBRARY_DIRS "/home/carlos/webrtc/webrtc-checkout/src/out/Release/obj/third_party/libyuv")
set(LIBYUV_INCLUDE_DIRS "/home/carlos/webrtc/webrtc-checkout/src/third_party/libyuv/include")

set(LIBWEBRTC_INCLUDE_DIRS "/home/carlos/webrtc/webrtc-checkout/src")
set(LIBWEBRTC_LIBRARY_DIRS "/home/carlos/webrtc/webrtc-checkout/src/out/Release/obj")

include_directories(${LIBWEBRTC_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${LIBWEBRTC_LIBRARY_DIRS})

include_directories(${JSONCPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${JSONCPP_LIBRARY_DIRS})

include_directories(${LIBYUV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${LIBYUV_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DWEBRTC_POSIX -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=gnu++0x -pthread")


#[[ Included Libraries

  - LibWebRTC
  - LibWebRTC_Common
  - LibX11
  - LibICE
  - LibSM
  - LibXext
  - Libdl
  - Librt
  - LibJsoncpp

]]

set(LIBWEBRTC_LIBRARIES /home/carlos/webrtc/webrtc-checkout/src/out/Release/obj/webrtc/libwebrtc.a;/home/carlos/webrtc/webrtc-checkout/src/out/Release/obj/webrtc/libwebrtc_common.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so;dl;rt;/home/carlos/webrtc/webrtc-checkout/src/build/linux/debian_jessie_amd64-sysroot/usr/lib/libjsoncpp.a)

file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.cc)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node 
   ${SOURCES}
)

# WebRTC Libraries
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
  ${LIBWEBRTC_LIBRARIES}
)

# GTK libraries
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
  ${GTK3_LIBRARIES}
)

# JSONCPP libraries
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node 
  ${JSONCPP_LIBRARIES}
)
```

It seems a problem with Json library, but, as you can check in code, it is already included.

On the other hand, it could be a problem with internal json library, but it is supposed to be included in libwebrtc.a so, what could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with the Json library, rather you are missing some required `.a` files. For example, the following link error:

```
conductor.cc:(.text._ZN3rtc9ArrayViewINS_13IntervalRangeELln4711EEC2IS1_EEPT_m[_ZN3rtc9ArrayViewINS_13IntervalRangeELln4711EEC5IS1_EEPT_m]+0xd4): undefined reference to `rtc::FatalMessage::FatalMessage(char const*, int, std::string*)'
```

indicates you're missing the `.a` that defines `rtc::FatalMessage::FatalMessage`.

`rtc::FatalMessage::FatalMessage` is defined in [checks.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/rtc_base/checks.cc) and is built by this [BUILD.gn](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/rtc_base/BUILD.gn) file.

Previously, `rtc::FatalMessage::FatalMessage` was included in the [webrtc_base static library](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/edc6e57a92d2b366871f4c2d2e926748326017b9/webrtc/base/BUILD.gn#126), but it looks like it has been renamed in the most recent versions. It appears that the static library target that contains `rtc::FatalMessage::FatalMessage` is now *rtc_base*.

One of the problems with `.a` files is that they do not have information (like a `.so`) describing what they depend on, so it's up to you at link time to make sure you get all the required files, which can be a real pain when there are a lot of `.a` files. If you have the freedom to move away from CMake for you main project, you could integrate with the WebRTC framework's GN build system, which will help you handle linking to the correct dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The library `webrtc.a` is not quite a stand-alone library unfortunately, at least not for branch-heads/72. It requires a number of additional third-party dependencies, *and* you have to build with specific compiler / linker flags to make it all work.

Based on the results of my own projects, the libraries required are

```
    rtc_base/json.o
    third_party/jsoncpp/json_reader.o
    third_party/jsoncpp/json_writer.o
    third_party/jsoncpp/json_value.o
    test/field_trial.o
    X11 Xcomposite Xext Xrender atomic dl pthread rt
    gmodule-2.0 gtk-3 gdk-3 pangocairo-1.0 pango-1.0
    atk-1.0 cairo-gobject cairo gdk_pixbuf-2.0 gio-2.0
    gobject-2.0 gthread-2.0 glib-2.0 m jsoncpp
```

With respect to the first error (typeinfo), you either need to build webrtc with RTTI enabled or add `-fno-rtti` to your compiler flags. RTTI is disabled by default in webrtc builds.

To see a list of compiler flags used to build the peerconnection_client example, check out the beginning of the peerconnection_client.ninja file generated in your out directory.

If you’re interested, I wrote a little generator script that extracts files necessary for getting started. It even generates a cmake file to include in your projects. I use it for quickly setting up my own native webrtc cmake projects. *(At the time of writing this, the script only supports linux-amd64 but can easily be extended for other platforms and architectures.)*
https://github.com/TekuConcept/WebRTCExamples/